# Are the tolls to school an education tax write off?

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction

My wife is enrolled in a college that the only way for us to get there is via toll roads and a couple of bridges. It costs almost $30 per day.

This wasn't an issue last semester because all of her classes were on a single day.

This semester, none of her classes are on the same day, so that is over $100/week we are spending on tolls. Can any part of these at least be written off on our taxes?

Comment: Are there no public transit options?

Comment: @warren - There are, but because we live outside of the major city, we have to bus into the city, subway to a train and it costs about the same and takes two times longer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately, transportation to school, including tolls, is not a deductible educational expense.

From the IRS's [Qualified Educational Expenses page](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/qualified-ed-expenses):

> Expenses that Do Not Qualify
>
> Even if you pay the following expenses to enroll or attend the school, the following are not qualified education expenses:
>
> - Room and board
> - Insurance
> - Medical expenses (including student health fees)
> - **Transportation**
> - Similar personal, living or family expenses

Comment: Well, now I need to find a way to take/make $2000/year from something else. Money life hack: Don't go to school in the North East if you don't live near it.